# Mostrar Popups de GeoJSON en Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, popup, geojson, mapa

debido a un proyecto sin fines de lucros me he visto en la necesidad de preparar un mapa básico en Leaflet a partir de un GeoJSON (primera vez que utilizo Leaflet), sin embargo, necesito mostrar los popups con todos los campos del GeoJSON.

Hasta ahora solo me permite mostrar un solo campo (pais) tipo string al añadirlo luego de .properties; el resto de los campos numéricos no los muestra. Necesito que aparezcan todos los campos en el popup. Cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar estaré muy agradecido, saludos!

Dejo acá parte del código:

```
    "type" : "FeatureCollection",
    "name" : "BDMapaWebGeneral012022",
    "features" : [
        {
            "type" : "Feature",
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [ -66.11093, 8.00187 ]
            },
            "properties" : {
                "codpais" : 58,
                "miembros" : 1,
                "pais" : "Venezuela",
                "x" : -66.11093,
                "y" : 8.00187
            }
        }
    ]
}

L.geoJSON(BDmiembros, {
    style: function(feature){
        return {
            color: '#100',
            weight: 0.5
        }
    },
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        if(feature.geometry.type=="Point")
        {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties)
    }
}}).addTo(myMap)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función bindPopup recibe un string como parámetro. Puedes convertir .properties a una cadena de caracteres utilizando el método "stringify" de la clase JSON ya que la propiedad .properties es un objeto de JavaScript equivalente a un JSON object. Intenta esto en la función onEachFeature

```
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) { 
   if(feature.geometry.type=="Point")
        {
        layer.bindPopup(JSON.stringify(feature.properties))
 }
}
```